# How Do I Make A Scrolling Title, But It Continuously Adds New Random Strings Of Text Forever

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a continuation of another code snippet I found on here. Here's the idea:

I have an array of random strings, and I want this:

```
function updatePageTitle(text) {
  document.title = text;
  setTimeout(function () {
      updatePageTitle(text.substr(1) + text.substr(0, 1));
  }, 150);
}
```

to output something like this:
(original text string) + new string + new string + new string (into infinity)

and have the new strings be randomized with this code:

```
var titles = ["string one", "string 2", "string 3"];
var title = titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)];
newString = title
```

is there a way to do this? like can I make it do the function here every time the current string it is reading is finished?